# Can I add headers to httpCall method in envoy lua filter?

Tags: lua, envoyproxy

I try add more headers to `httpCall` method, but upstream can't received.
example lua script:
`lua
request_handle:httpCall(
    "service1",
    {
     [":method"] = "POST",
     [":path"] = "/",
     [":authority"] = "lua_cluster",
     [":authorization"] = "Basic 123456"
    },
    "",
    1000)`
 
Does it have 3 headers?

Comment: The  envoy source (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/source/extensions/filters/http/lua/lua_filter.cc#L137) seems right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define any header as below.

```
request_handle:httpCall(
    "service1",
    {
     [":method"] = "POST",
     [":path"] = "/",
     [":authority"] = "lua_cluster",
     ["authorization"] = "Basic 123456",
     ["any-header"] = "header-value"
    },
    "",
    1000)
```